# Why does gcc not provide the AVX512F intrinsic for absolute value of floats?

Tags: gcc, avx512

Short question: the Intel Intrinsics Guide https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide says that `_mm512_abs_ps` is available for AVX512F. However, gcc 5.4 doesn't seem to provide this intrinsic. Why is this? Does it appear in later gcc versions?

Comment: There is no special instruction for it; it's just a convenience wrapper for `_mm512_and_epi32` with the right mask.  (Because AVX512F doesn't include `vandps`, only `vpandd`, so using the intrinsic would take some casting to keep the compiler happy).  [EVEX `vandps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ANDPS.html) is part of AVX512DQ.  I didn't check on http://godbolt.org/ if later gcc has it.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Thanks! When looking for some other missing intrinsics I found this page: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-04/msg00374.html, so apparently, they where just forgotten (including the abs intrinsic).

Comment: @PeterCordes GCC is missing a lot of intrinsics. And a lot of the ones they have, have the wrong prototype. (mainly the pointer types for load-store instrinsics) Not sure if they're ever gonna fix them.